# I could not get data "session" from express session

Tags: express, frontend, express-session

This is my code:

```
//Express Session
const express = require("express");
app.use(
  expressSession({
    secret: "keyboard cat",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: true, maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 3 },
  })
);
```

Save session:

```
(req,res)=>{
  req.session.userId = "this is session";
}
```

Retrieve session:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log("session parameter: ", req.session);
});
```

I got :

```
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2023-03-16T00:34:35.139Z,
    originalMaxAge: 180000,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true
  }
}
```

However, I did not find userId that I saved. Please Help! Thanks very much.

I trid the official document：

```
var app = express()
app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true }
}))

// Use the session middleware
app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}))

// Access the session as req.session
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.views) {
    req.session.views++
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
    res.write('<p>views: ' + req.session.views + '</p>')
    res.write('<p>expires in: ' + (req.session.cookie.maxAge / 1000) + 's</p>')
    res.end()
  } else {
    req.session.views = 1
    res.end('welcome to the session demo. refresh!')
  }
})
```

But I could not get the execution right.

Comment: Where you store the `userId` in `req.session`?

Comment: {
req.session.userId = "this is session";
}

This coding is setting "this is session" in req.session.userId in the Official document.